# Is it right way to use different message brokers for publisher and subscriber

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Is it right way to use **`ZeroMQ`** as publisher and **`RabbitMQ`** as subscriber in software architecture?

Publisher uses `ZeroMQ` as message broker and my **`Node.js`** application needs to subscribe to a topic using `RabbitMQ` ( as `RabbitMQ` node package doesn't need prerequisites as `ZeroMQ` requires `python` & `.NET` framework to be installed ).

And also, Publisher uses different `ZeroMQ` library, other than the one required for `Node.js`.

Comment: Without knowing to much about your architecture and about ZeroMQ, why your architecture not use only RabbitMQ for example?

Answer (score 1):

### Speaking about Architecture?
`Prologue:`

A first note to be made is, **`ZeroMQ` is a broker-less** messaging/signalling framework. If your architecture needs a Broker, you either have to pick from other COTS shelf, or implement a custom-specific Broker-factory on your own.

### `The Tower of Babel:`

Deployment pre-requisities are not a sufficient argument to stop thinking or to sacrifice an elementary logic of operations.

If one considers a **proprietary protocol A** `sender` to be a-priori interconnectable with a **proprietary protocol B** `receiver` to be a fair assumption, there is hard to help or explain the root cause of the trouble.

While `ZeroMQ` documentation includes a published set of **ZMQ-Protocol-Proposals** from their very origin in their respective RFC-states, there is no expressed warranty, AFAIK, the other "end-of-the-phone-line" understands and fully cooperates within the `ZeroMQ` specification with the "remote-caller", unless a mutually agreed compatibility is assured by the protocol design owners ( which would be well popularised, in case one has undertaken such efforts, which is hardly to become a reality due to lack of any business-motivated reasons to develop a product just to declare a compatibility with another protocol engine, which is for about a decade well adopted in FOSS domain ).

Sorry, this would never fly.

### `How to repair the flawed architecture?`

The best one can do is to seek for a minimum common multiple - getting all heterogeneous systems capable to use the same messaging/signalling framework ( sharing the guaranteed cross-compatible protocol suite, different versions may and do appear in such designs due to external constraints ).

Candidates with light-weight resources requirements' footprints, almost linearly scaleable, ultimate speed / low latency and minimum pre-requisities are usually preferred:

- **`ZeroMQ`**
- **`nanomsg`**

would be the first I would test the architecture to have 'em system-wide deployed.

### **`Good Hunt!`**